# Flyertalk level of questions?

Tags: discussion

Does the whole of [flyertalk forums](http://www.flyertalk.com/) fit into the scope of this site?

> Welcome to the world's most popular frequent flyer community!
>
> FlyerTalk is an interactive community that provides up-to-date information on travel-related loyalty reward programs. It's the hub that brings everyone together -- from leisure travelers to mileage junkies -- to converse about programs, get the latest program buzz or discuss how to maximize points or miles. You'll even get some good general travel information!

Can this site be a better flyertalk?

Comment: What is a "flyertalk"?

Comment: Flyertalk.com click on forums. It's the expert traveller site right now.

Comment: Hmm I had never heard of it. I used Lonely Planet thorn tree in the past when I needed something.

Comment: Is Flyertalk international or US in scope?

Answer (score 8):

I would think that the topics covered on Flyertalk are in general also on topic for this site. After all, any aspect of flying is also an aspect of travel.

The only things about Flyertalk that I would consider to be off-topic here are the subjective (and honestly, very boring) questions like "is Lufthansa first class better than United?". Discussion of which things are better based on subjective, vague, criteria is probably off-topic.

As for whether we can be a "better forum" - like VMAtm said, this is not a forum, or really a place for discussion, so I don't think that this site is really competing with -  or has the same aims as - Flyertalk.

Answer (score 3):

Every site on stackexchange is a Q & A site, not traditional forum.
All you can do - organize a [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) and create there a chat room for this.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that questions dealing with specific destinations often only use the three-letter airport codes. I agree that they help in shortening questions and standardizing route descriptions, but for most users on this site, those codes are close to meaningless. Apart from that, these questions should be welcome here.